# How to replace rows based on conditions?

Tags: r, if-statement, dataframe

This is a very simple request, but I can't wrap my head around it.  I've created a flag variable (0,1), and I would like to replace the values of one column with another conditionally on if flag==1.

Here is a reproducible example and my incorrect code:

```
if_else(q46$flag==1,q46$name==q46$positions,q46$name==q46$name)

set.seed(123)
q46 <- data.frame(flag=sample(0:1,100,replace=T),
       name=sample(c('Bob','Susan','Susan','Amy','Elliot'),100, replace=T),
      positions=sample(c('President','Agronomist','Preacher'),100,replace=T))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try following,also, your code should working fine, just add `stringsAsFactors = F`, when create the `data.frame` `if_else(q46$flag==1,q46$positions,q46$name)`

```
q46$name[q46$flag==1]=q46$positions[q46$flag==1]
```

---

Data

```
 q46 <- data.frame(flag=sample(0:1,100,replace=T),
                      name=sample(c('Bob','Susan','Susan','Amy','Elliot'),100, replace=T),
                      positions=sample(c('President','Agronomist','Preacher'),100,replace=T),stringsAsFactors = F)
```

Comment: I like the elegance and simplicity of  q46$name[q46$flag==1]=q46$positions[q46$flag==1].  Using indexing seems like an easier and more obvious approach for me.

Answer (score 2):

```
set.seed(123)
q46 <- data.frame(flag=sample(0:1,100,replace=T),
                  name=sample(c('Bob','Susan','Susan','Amy','Elliot'),100, replace=T),
                  positions=sample(c('President','Agronomist','Preacher'),100,replace=T))


q46$name = with(q46, ifelse(flag, as.character(positions), as.character(name)))
```

You need to assign the output of `ifelse` into `q46$name` to replace it. The `as.character` conversion is based on the assumption that your `positions` and `name` columns are factors (They will automatically be converted to factors if you don't add `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` when creating your data.frame).

Result:

```
> head(q46, 10)
   flag       name  positions
1     0      Susan  President
2     1   Preacher   Preacher
3     0      Susan Agronomist
4     1 Agronomist Agronomist
5     1 Agronomist Agronomist
6     0     Elliot   Preacher
7     1 Agronomist Agronomist
8     1  President  President
9     1  President  President
10    0        Bob  President
```

Comment: Couldn't you have used `head(q46, 10)` or so?

Comment: @RuiBarradas Good idea